# Find pattern then split by ending new line

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find a specific pattern then split the text by the following ending line. For example my text would look something similar to this

```
{11/2/2018 8:09 AM} This item was created by. -John Doe 
{11/2/2018 10:56 AM} This item was upated by -Sue Smith 
{11/2/2018 10:58 AM} Does this item handle multiple lines? 
Yes it does -Jane Sample
```

I am currently using the following javascript

```
var Notes = data.Notes.split(/-[\w ]+$/gmi);
$.each(Notes, function (index, note) {
    console.log(note)
})
```

Which does work kinda perfect, it breaks the text into the follow lines

---

```
{11/2/2018 8:09 AM} This item was created by.
```

---

```
{11/2/2018 10:56 AM} This item was upated by
```

---

```
{11/2/2018 10:58 AM} Does this item handle multiple lines? 
Yes it does
```

---

but as you can see it removed the username...

How would I write it so that I split the string at that specific pattern but keep the username at the end of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `.match` instead of `.split`:

```js
const text = `{11/2/2018 8:09 AM} This item was created by. -John Doe
{11/2/2018 10:56 AM} This item was upated by -Sue Smith
{11/2/2018 10:58 AM} Does this item handle multiple lines?
Yes it does -Jane Sample`;

const notes = text.match(/^[\s\S]*?-[\w ]+$/mg) || [];

for (const note of notes) {
  console.log(note);
}
```

`.split` lets you specify what to throw away. `.match` lets you specify what to keep. Here we want to extract any text, as short as possible (`[\s\S]*?`) up to the next occurrence of a name (`-[\w ]+$`).

Comment: Thank you... I don't why I didn't think to do match instead of split... slow Friday. lol